# HTML FontAwesome

Tags: html, icons, adobe-indesign, glyphicons

I am working with fontawesome 5.0.13 and all of a sudden the last icons that I added decided to not show up on InDesign. I am fairly new with html and fontawesome in general. So any help will be appreciated.
What I do is copy and paste the code for each icon in the doc below. Then I copy the glyph and paste it on my InDesign file. From there, I only need to select the icon and change the font to FontAwesome. The problem started when I changed the font to FontAwesome and instead of coming to form, the icon would disappear. Any ideas why?
 Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>


    <i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>

    <i class="fab fa-wpexplorer"></i>

    <i class="fab fa-cc-discover"></i>

    <i class="fab fa-searchengin"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-tty"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-spin"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-battery-full"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-portrait"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-database"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-plane"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-globe"></i>

    <i  class="fas fa-toolbox"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>

    <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-book"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-book fas-spin"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-flag-checkered"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-building"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-spin"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-flask"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-sitemaps fa-3x"></i>

    <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>

    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>

    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-mouse-pointer"></i>

    <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should be able to help, but I need some more information. Can you tell me what the end-use of the file is to be (i.e. website)? Also, are you coding your HTML using InDesign?

Comment: In order to use FontAwesome on Desktop, you need to download and install its font files. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-desktop/setup/getting-started